# How to list all the DataFrame names in a DataFrame list Object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm Just learning through pandas html lib and that's all is working , However if i would like to know all the DataFrame names in a DataFrame list Object(Data),  How could i do that?

Herein my DataFrame List is `Data`.

```
import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_html('http://openstacksearch/vm_list.html', header=0, flavor='bs4')
```

How to get the details of total DataFrame in a Pandas DataFrame list

Comment: do you mean `len(Data)` ?

Comment: @JonClements,  no  that i know and not really useful for me, my intent here to understand how to get the details like name of the DataFrame in a DataFrameList as usually it says `Data` is DataFrameList   not a DataFrame , so i'm Keen to Know then how to check that how many DataFrame i have in my DataFrameList .

Comment: your code should always return a list of `DataFrame` objects... not sure what you mean here? What is the name for instance? Are you looking to get the id of the table or something? What you're doing will just attempt to take every table and convert it to a DF.

Comment: So, DataFrame objects actually contains a list elements. for instance data1 = Data[0] is my DataFrame for my code. `Data[0]` simply refers to the first dataframe (index 0) in the list of dataframes (Data) returned by pd.read_html()?  so, every index indeed is a DataFrame, that's true..

Comment: Do you need a sum of length of the all DataFrames or apply another funtion to your `Data` and get a summary? I.e. something like this: `sum([len(df) for df in Data])` or `[df.describe() for df in Data]`?

Comment: @MikhailStepanov, i need the name of all DataFrames (DataFrame names) which i have in my DataFrame list object.

Comment: In Python, lists do not have named elements. Dicts, named tuples, and other types however do. Consider converting your list to these types by giving them names. Then `mydict.keys()` would be all names.

Comment: @Parfait, Thanks for your inputs, i'll consider that.